# Copy an element of struct array to another struct of same types

Tags: c++

If there is a structure:

```
struct Student // Student structure to store student's records
{
int rollno; // student rollno
string name; // student name
string address; // address
int pno; // phone number
};
```

and int main() contains

```
int main()
{
Student *s;
s= new Student [10];
}
```

Then how can we assign a struct to a different struct of same types?

```
void arrange()
{
Student *p= new Student;
//    int temp;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                if (s[i].rollno > s[j].rollno)
                {
                    p = s[i];
                    s[i] = s[j];
                    s[j] = p;
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't use **bold** format in markup formatted code. Use `*p = s[i];`and `s[j] = *p;` to make assignments to/from `p`.

Comment: There is no need in writing everything in bold.

Comment: thanks .... it's the first time i am using ... thats why  ...

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE. Your code has a variable in the scope of `main()` and you try to use it in `arrange()`.

Comment: it doesn't gives an error but void arrange() also doesnt executes :-/
*p = s[i];
s[i] = s[j];
s[j] = *p;

Comment: It's not executed, because you're not calling it anywhere.

Comment: – πάντα ῥεῖ i m calling it in int main (), anyway thanks the problem solved :-)

Comment: @Shaan Sorry, I can't spot the call in `main()` above!

Comment: – πάντα ῥεῖ sorry i didn't wrote it above but in the editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Than how can we assign a struct to a different struct of same types

Just copy construct it:

```
int main()
{
    Student s[10]; // array of 10 students
    Student student = s[5]; // copy of 6th element of array
}
```

You are over-complicating things with all those pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare p as a pointer to a student then the `struct` is accessed by `*p`. So you should write:

```
*p = s[i];
s[i] = s[j];
s[j] = *p;
```

However, I don't think having a pointer is of any use here. Just write

```
Student p;
```